# Batch replace string in every subfolder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, batch-rename

Is it possible to batch replace a text string inside a cmd file in every subfolder?

**The folder structure is:**

Root Folder (Batch script) > Several subfolders > `job(folder number)_EncodeAudio.cmd` > text string

The cmd file has the `128` string that should be replaced to `384` and each subfolder (job1, job2, job3) has the same `job(folder number)_EncodeAudio.cmd` file.

**This is better explained in a single image**:

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be a batch script? PowerShell makes things like this trivial.

Comment: Yes, preferably a BAT file.

Comment: That's unfortunate. If you decide otherwise, something like `Get-ChildItem *.bat -Recurse | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 128 384 } | Set-Content $_ }` should work.

Comment: Your script returns an error: 
`Unexpected token '384' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken`

Comment: Added a comma between both numbers and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Billy's script and a BAT to call the Powershell script.

BAT file:

```
CD /D %root% C:\Root Folder Location
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -file batch.ps1
```

PS1 file:

```
Get-ChildItem *.cmd -Recurse | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '128','384' } | Set-Content $_ }
```

Comment: This script changes file encoding to ascii and adds a newline at the end of the files